# Call recording and reports are not generating in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-connect

Call recording and reports are not generating in S3 bucket .
S3 bucket is created but call recording and reports are not saved . I have added Set call recording behavior in contact flow before customer inputs but even then nothing is saved in S3 . S3 bucket has all the permission of read , write, update.

Can someone help me with this , I am stuck with this issue from last two days .

[image]
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For recording to be generated you must enable recording in the contact flow used by the call. Once recording is enabled for a given call, the recording file will appear in the S3 bucket shortly after the call ends.

Note that recordings only occur when the caller is connected to an agent, LEX/ interactions are never recorded.

For reports, the S3 bucket only serves as a target location for scheduled exports of reports. If you don’t have any reports exports scheduled then you will never see anything in the reports bucket.

Comment: I am doing the same things which you have suggested , added an screenshot if it helps .

Comment: Do I need to enable data streaming and amazon kinesis for call recording .

Comment: Hi @RahulPanwar, I edited my answer to be more clear about when recordings are actually captured. Based on the screen shot you provided, recording would not occur since the call is never delivered to an agent via a queue. IVR and LEX interactions can not be recorded.

Comment: You don’t need to enable data streaming for recordings.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your screenshot the call is never connected to an agent. Call recording will not start until the call is connected to an agent.