# Amazon connect unable to save recording in s3 bucket

Tags: lambda, s3-bucket, amazon-connect, call-recording

Amazon Connect is able to process the outbound calls and inbound calls, have an option to record calls in S3 bucket, I have made path settings in Data Storage administrator, but am still unable to see recordings in s3 bucket, is there any other alternate solution to store recordings in Amazon connect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call recording and reports are not generating in S3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51981531/call-recording-and-reports-are-not-generating-in-s3-bucket)

Answer (score 1):

You don’t have to create the “path”, it is actually part of the file name in S3.

The reason you’re not seeing the recordings is either because you have not enabled recording in the contact flow or because the call never reaches an agent. See my answer to this question for more detail: [Call recording and reports are not generating in S3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51981531/call-recording-and-reports-are-not-generating-in-s3-bucket/52012105#52012105)

Regarding other recording solutions, no you can’t use anything else to record calls.

Comment: I have set the contact flow already, but still, I cannot see the recording in s3 bucket

Comment: I am trying to test myself by calling to my mobile, even then it's not working @aossey

Comment: If you’re making outbound calls from the CCP then you have to set recoding behavior in the contact flow assigned to the outbound whisper flow for agent.

Comment: thanks a lot aossey but my idea is contact flow bot has to be recorded is that possible?

Comment: No, only agent conversations can be recorded. LEX (bot) conversations are not recordable. This is a common misunderstand, which I highlighted in the answer to the other question I linked as duplicate.